# How to call an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

So I am trying to write a program with a list of 7 movies. I have to use an array so I defined them as follows. Then in my Welcome method I want to reference the array but also number it. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track and I do not understand the error I am getting in line with system.out.print...:
The error says something about MOVIE(int) is undefined, but I tried adding the method and it does not do what I want it to do.

```
public class OnDemandMovieHitsClass
{

private static final String[] MOVIES = {"The Avengers", "Jurassic World", "Titanic", "Star Wars: Episode " +
        "VII - The Force Awakens","The Martian", "The Notebook", "Interstellar"};   

private static final double[] COST = {8, 9.5, 4.5, 12, 10, 5, 7.5}; 

public OnDemandMovieHitsClass()
{

}
public void Welcome()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {   
        System.out.println((i+1) + "." + MOVIES(i));
    }
```

Comment: what is the line 17 and error?

Comment: @FastSnail, I edited the post clarifying a bit.

Comment: System.out.println((i+1) + "." + MOVIES[i]);

Comment: Thanks! I had to look at that for a second before I realized the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MOVIES` is an array. If you want to index into it the correct syntax is `MOVIES[i]`.

You're getting an error that complains about `MOVIES(int)` being undefined because of the method syntax but that method apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I keep missing simple things like that.

Comment: Glad to help. Simple errors like that happen to the best of us. If you'd like to show your appreciation feel free to up-vote or accept the answer. @Sarah.

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me. Can you explain the reputation aspect of this site? It says my vote up won't be public until my reputation is 15.

Comment: @Sarah, I think [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) will do a much better job than I at explaining reputation on the site. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks, explains enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

Index into an array by using `MOVIES[i]`, not `MOVIES(i)`